# Where can I view quarantine or other COVID-19 requirements for airline crew?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, quarantine, cabin-crew

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php sometimes mentions quarantine or other COVID-19 requirements for airline crew, e.g. for Thailand:

> 13. Airline crew are subject to self-isolation until their next flight.

but sometimes it doesn't, e.g. for Taiwan nothing is said about the airline crew:

> 4. Passengers are subject to quarantine for 14 days.

whereas the [airline crew do have to quarantine](https://www.cdc.gov.tw/En/Bulletin/Detail/a-SVOMqxKLi4HbPU9tPpgw?typeid=158) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210502100915/https://www.cdc.gov.tw/En/Bulletin/Detail/a-SVOMqxKLi4HbPU9tPpgw?typeid=158)), albeit in some cases for a much shorter period:

> - Crew members arriving from countries under Level 3 travel notice (long-haul flights): 3 days of home quarantine (an RT-PCR on the last day of the period is required, and a negative test result is also required) and 11 days of self-health management.
> - Crew members who have not entered countries under Level 3 travel notice and have returned to Taiwan the same day (short-haul flights):14 days of self-health management
>   etc.

Where can I view quarantine or other COVID-19 requirements for airline crew? E.g., is there some https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php equivalent for airline crew?

Comment: If you're air crew, then quarantine requirements would be something taken care of by your employer. Not all countries have to advertise their policy, nor do they have to apply the same policy to all airlines.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks, great info, you're welcome to add it as an answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really related to ordinary travel and the linked followup question has already been removed.

Comment: @GregHewgill no idea why you would exclude airline crews from a travel website.

Comment: Airline crews are employees of airlines and the various concerns about entry to and exit from other countries are entirely a matter for their employer. The [Help Center](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically excludes "work visas", which would apply to airline crews because they need to enter other countries as a consequence of their work.

Comment: @GregHewgill work visas have nothing to do with quarantine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the comment section, a equivalent of https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php mentioning quarantine or other COVID-19 requirements for airline crew for any country would be infeasible, because:

1. Some countries don't make such policies publicly available,
2. The policy may dependent on the airline.

Comment:

> If you're air crew, then quarantine requirements would be something taken care of by your employer. Not all countries have to advertise their policy, nor do they have to apply the same policy to all airlines. – [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill) [May 18 at 2:30](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163798/where-can-i-view-quarantine-or-other-covid-19-requirements-for-airline-crew#comment412315_163798)

---

This led me to this follow-up question: [Why would a country apply different quarantine policies for airline crews to different airlines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/163829/1810)

Answer in the comment section:

> Obvious potential answers are the origin country's sanitary situation, reciprocity and company policies (e.g. regarding regular testing of crews, movement restrictions/bubbles). – [xngtng](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/65267/xngtng) [2 days ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163829/why-would-a-country-apply-different-quarantine-policies-for-airline-crews-to-dif#comment412422_163829)